# jquery re ordering <li> according to url parameters

Tags: jquery, url, reorderlist

I want to reordering my list of items according to the parameters in the URL.

Here's my list:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href='page.php?paramValue=1'>iten1</a></li>
   <li><a href='page.php?paramValue=2'>iten2</a></li>
   <li><a href='page.php?paramValue=3'>iten3</a></li>
   <li><a href='page.php?paramValue=4'>iten4</a></li>
```

and if for example  the url its: *mydomain.com/page.php?paramValue=3* the list sould reordering and the 3rd li should become the first one in the list, when the page load (When any iten is clicked the page loads agian), like this:

```
<ul>
       <li><a href='page.php?paramValue=3'>iten3</a></li>
       <li><a href='page.php?paramValue=1'>iten1</a></li>
       <li><a href='page.php?paramValue=2'>iten2</a></li>           
       <li><a href='page.php?paramValue=4'>iten4</a></li>
   </ul>
```

Any tips??

Comment: What code have you come with so far? Does the ul have an id? Is it the only ul on page?

Comment: at the moment I have code to read the URL and split the string. No it's not the only ul in the page. I can give it an ID

Comment: [This frequently-asked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript) has a few good approaches for getting variable values from a query string.

Comment: A `tip` would be to do this via PHP vs jQuery or JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

The code below looks for a `href` that ends with `3` grabs the parent (li) and prepends it it to the ul.

```
$('a[href$="3"]').parent().prependTo('ul');
```

Add more exacting selectors as relevant.

http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/DDAvY/2/

**Update:**

The following is a little more precise. The code below looks for a `href` that **contains** `paramValue=3`

```
$('a[href*="paramValue=3"]').parent().prependTo('ul');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/DDAvY/4/

Comment: How exactly does that get the value from the page URL?

Comment: @AndrewWillis "Looks for a href that ends with 3..."

Comment: so where do you get the '3' from? It needs to come from the page URL

Comment: @AndrewWillis Read the updated answer. Review the [jQuery attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/). All - Revengeful down votes stink.

Comment: again, You are not getting that number from the URL of the page, which is required and specified in the question. if somebody visits http://example.com/index.php?paramValue=4 then how would you get 'paramValue=4' and use that to re-order the li's?

Comment: The OP commented that he already has code to get the variable value from the query string. And even if he hadn't, [that particular question is already well-answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript).

Comment: Still 3 is hardcoded. It should be referred through a variable in which value is extracted by another code.

Comment: Jesus. If the OP can't extrapolate how to replace a string with a variable then he can comment.

Comment: You are giving an answer and so you should not make an assumption what can be done something in other's code. Moreover your answer should have a placeholder for such a variable so that one can go through your answer and understand your assumptions.

Comment: I think I just met my first Stack Troll.

Comment: @iambriansreed It worked nice. Just needed to add a class name to <a> elements and in your code also added the class name like this $('a.className[href*="paramValue=3"]')..... like I said to Amit Bhargava, I already got a piece of code that reads the URL parameters every time the page loads. Thanks all

Comment: @user794035 Nice to know after all this question's trolling you picked the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code. Have not tested, but should work.

```
var ulElement = $("ul"); // this may change if you want a specific ul element.
var linkElems = window.location.href.replace(/.*\?/,"").split('&');
var paramValueStr = "";
for (var i=0; i < linkElems.length; i++) {
    if (linkElems[i].indexOf("paramValue") == 0) {
        paramValueStr  = linkElems[i];
    }
}
if (paramValueStr == "") {
    return;
}

var elemToRemove = ulElement.find('a [href*="' + paramValueStr + '"]').parent();
elemToRemove.remove(); // remove from original place
elemToRemove.prependTo(ulElement); // insert into beginning of ul
```

Comment: Just saying that it is very complex is a vague argument and it means that you did not go through answer. You should care to be more specific when you give a feedback.

Comment: Dude. Complex means you did in **13** lines what I did in **1** line.

Comment: "The OP commented that he already has code to get the variable value from the query string. And even if he hadn't, [that particular question is already well-answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript)." - @mblase75

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they will always be the same, you can use string.split() to get the number after the value:

```
href = $(a).attr('href');
href.split()
//href is now an array[page.php?paramValue, number];
//you can use href[1] to sort the elements.
```

If you'd like to continue JQUery, there is a plugin built for just that:

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/

If you use that plugin, your code would look something like this:

```
$('li').sortElements(function(a, b){
    aHref = $(a).attr('href');
    bHref = $(b).attr('href');
    aHref = aHref.split();
    bHref = bHref.split();
    return aHref[1] > bHref[1] ? 1 : -1;
});
```

Admittedly, this could probably be made more pretty, but it should work

Comment: I don't know, was part of the user agreement for SA to be the snarkiest possible? On a side note, thank you for the opportunity to learn that prepend will actually delete a node to prepend it. That is likely to be useful to me.

Comment: @iambriansreed. WIll your solution work? Can you post a sample of how your solution would work?

Comment: A link to a fiddle is in my answer... @ChrisSobolewski ;)

Answer (score -1):

try this:

javascript:

```
elementID = /[0-9]+/.exec(/paramValue=[0-9]+/.exec(location.search));
$('li:nth-child('+elementID+')', 'ul#ulID').prependTo('ul#ulID');
```

you could also do this:

```
elementID = /[0-9]+/.exec(/paramValue=[0-9]+/.exec(location.search));
$('ul#ulID').prepend($('li:nth-child('+elementID+')', 'ul#ulID')
```

Comment: I just changed the way to find elementID because I had a bit of a massive error!

Comment: Will it work if there are more than one parameter? Note that this url is just an example and later another parameter can be added into the url and then code will break.

Comment: Do you mean multiple paramValue values? if the URL is ?paramValue=3&otherthing=45, it will still work as it only searches for the 'paramValue=[0-9]+' string, returns that string and then takes the number from it.

Comment: interesting approach, i liked it. Also you are assuming that elementId will be at elementId index, which is kind of very specific and better way is to search the element which matches it.

Comment: Yeah I see your point, however if the list is initially in order then really the elementID should also be the index.

Comment: That is why I said 'better way'. What if it was 0-based values or it was a-based values, or values are not continuous integers for example (1,3,5,7).

In any case, this would work.